# ExtJS 5: Reserve space for msg target

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I have a form in ExtJS 5 that displays error markers beside form fields, then the positioning of other form fields changes all the time, depending on whether there are validation markers or not.

As soon as a validation marker appears, the layout is rearranged to accommodate this new element.

From a user point of view, this evokes a feeling of instability.

Is it possible to somehow reserve space for the validation markers up-front, such that they only appear/disappear, without re-positioning all the other components within the layout?

Comment: It's certainly possible. How? It depends on how your error message is shown. A more specific answer will require the question to be more specific, e.g. with a fiddle showcase.

Comment: You could probably use tooltip to display the error message rather than msgTarget. this will not affect your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `autoFitErrors: false` option on the field. [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-autoFitErrors).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to definitely display error / error marker next to the field, you could add an empty container of specified sizes and add an error message to it when necessary, here's a simple example (place `messageContainer` container in the right place for you): [static message box fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/q2c). *If you clarify your problem, I can update example.*

However, in my opinion, it would be appropriate to use tooltips or, even better, `vtype` ([link to docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-vtype)) with `vtypeText`, which will appear directly near incorrectly filled field. Check your form with `isValid` method ([link to docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-isValid)) in this case.